# Cannot install via npm for node on Windows

Tags: stellar-sdk, javascript-sdk

I'm trying to download the stellar SDK for my angular project but the npm install fails.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't have msbuild setup with NPM

If you're installing the newest version of sodium-native you need an MSBUILD here:
https://github.com/sodium-friends/sodium-native/blob/9d97f1d182138e89a54248d2e70fc3d412c8443c/preinstall.js#L62